# Calculating Average of Columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have these two tables.

```
t1
------|
pageid |

t2
-------|------
pageid |age
```

What I am trying to is run a select that will pull each pageid one by one from t1 and then compare to the pageids in t2 (t2 may have several pageids with the same value) and get the average of all ages in table t2 with the value just pulled from t1 and I want to do this for all pageids in t1. Here is my current SQL statement, it ends up taking the average of all the averages (I can elaborate more if needed).

```
Select AVG(age) from t2 INNER
JOIN t1 ON t2.pageid = t1.pageid;
```

If I use the following SQL statement

```
Select AVG(age) from t2 INNER
JOIN t1 ON t2.pageid = 1;
```

Then all average age of all pageids with a  value of 1 in t2 is calculated correctly. However, instead of just 1, I will need do this process for each pageid entry in t1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `t1.pageid` as a column in your select, and then add a `GROUP BY` on that column, and get rid of the `pageid = 1` filter:

```
Select t1.pageid, AVG(age) from t2 INNER
JOIN t1 ON t2.pageid = t1.pageid
group by t1.pageid;
```